# How to modify grub entry for supporting KGDB kernel image?

Tags: 10.04, kernel, grub2, server

I am trying to update target m/c grub.cfg file for KGDB setup but while booting the m/c it got hung completely and not asking/waiting for remote gdb connection. Following is the entry which I added:-

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-24-kgdb' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        recordfail
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 12878c3b-c553-4b4b-986a-6e32daea3ad1
        linux   /vmlinuz-2.6.32-kgdb root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root ro kgdbwait kgdboe=@192.168.140.23/,@192.168.140.158/  quiet
        initrd  /initrd.img-2.6.32-24-server
}
```

I have also compiled and copied /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.15.5-kgdb & /boot/System.map-2.6.15.5-kgdb to target m/c from devlopement m/c.

STD entry before adding KGDB in grub.cfg was:-

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-24-server' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        recordfail
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 12878c3b-c553-4b4b-986a-6e32daea3ad1
        linux   /vmlinuz-2.6.32-24-server root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root ro   quiet
        initrd  /initrd.img-2.6.32-24-server
}
```

Please suggest how to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `grub2` (which was the default in 10.04), menu entries should not be manually added to `grub.cfg`. Instead they can be added in  `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` or you can drop a new file in `/etc/grub.d/`. More GRUB2 info can be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Custom Menu Entries

As for the KGDB kernel itself, I'm certainly not an expert here. My understanding is that you need to also set `kgdb8250=<port number>,<port speed>`. You might try looking here for more KGDB specific help:

http://kgdb.linsyssoft.com/docu.htm